How to resolve updater problem without installing snap?
I installed Firefox from PPA and I have removed the snap package along with snapd itself and whatever is a snap.
Now sudo apt update fails because it is expecting the snap version of firefox to be installed. What do I do?
I have set the pins in preference.d but it still wants to upgrade firefox. The blog post I followed: https://www.debugpoint.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/. My Ubuntu is Noble Numbat.

You've provided few specifics; we don't know your release, nor what exactly you did. Many Ubuntu developers have blogged how to use deb packaged firefox/thunderbird etc and avoid problems with this (ie. not have snap packages return), but we don't know which blog you followed as you've not said, nor what actual steps you performed as you don't say. Tell us, and don't make us guess.

I think there may be an error in your question as well. You say not expecting and I think you meant expecting.

@David idk bro. firefox search highlights three words xd. Edit: I didn't catch that, twice. Thanks for telling me!

Did you follow the steps in https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466?

@guiverc yes you are right I will update the answer in a second.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Much Love! Edit: It Worked!!

You can close your question, by selecting it as a duplicate of the previously asked question. Also please upvote questions and answers that help you. That will help future users decide which posts are useful
